# use ts to refer to path

Tags: node.js, typescript

When I use ts to refer to path

use this

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
```

but `node index.ts`,something wrong

```
import * as path from 'path';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

node -version 12.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ES modules in node to use ES 6 imports.
https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-js-12-from-experimental-to-release/